# How to manage User Control in List Box using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i know that there are many question of this, but i don't find the correct answer, or i don't understand the correct way to solve.
I have my list box in the MainWindows, it is populated by custom object (FooObjClass).

```
<ListBox x:Name="FooListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <fooNameSpace:FooObjView/>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

the FooObjView is a User Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="PLCS7_TEST.SmartObjRecognize.SmartObjView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.FooObjRecognize"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:FooViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=FooObjprop.Name}"/> 
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=FooObjprop.Type}">
</Grid>
```

and this is my FooViewModel

```
 class FooViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private FooObjClass fooObjmember;

    public FooObjClass FooObjprop
    {
        get { return fooObjmember; }
        set
        {
            this.fooObjmember= value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("FooObjprop");
        }
    }
}
```

the FooObjClass is a normal class and the ObservableObject class is this:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpresssion);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void VerifyPropertyName(String propertyName)
    {
        // verify that the property name matches a real,  
        // public, instance property on this Object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            Debug.Fail("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what i can do for pass the item object of the list box (it's a FooObjClass ) to the last FooModelView? I have to use the Dependency Property? But How? I tryed and i readed all, but i don't find solution

With this piece of code i would to pass the item object of the list box to the FooViewModel

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:FooViewModel fooObjmember="{Databinding}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

but the fooObjmember is not a dependency property, and when i tried to create a dependency property it's the same

Thank you and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome,

*Here are your errors:*

- You're not specifying the binding for a ListBoxItem
- You are instantiating another model in the UserControl
- You are binding to field `fooObjmember`, only properties are allowed

Here's a working example:

**Window XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!--<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"> binds to DataContext property-->
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window code**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new List<MyModel>
            {
                new MyModel {Number = 1, Value = "one"},
                new MyModel {Number = 2, Value = "two"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**User control XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyModel}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Border Padding="5" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**User control code**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MyUserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model code**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    internal class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _number;
        private string _value;

        public int Number
        {
            get { return _number; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _number) return;
                _number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _value) return;
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Now adjust that to your needs :D

Comment: thanks @Aybe, i've set de listbox.Datacontext because i've other thinksin the window and i copied the rest from your code, it's all right without exeption but the datacontext in the user control is null. The list box have item inside.

Comment: it's the same that you posted, the only difference is in the window code. instead DataContext = new List<MyModel> i wrote listbox.Datacontext = new List<MyModel>. When i debug i see the object in the listbox but in the user control where i inserted var x = this.Datacontext (after InitializeComponent()) i see that it's null.

Comment: the class that I am using it's not directly the MyModel class, but MymodelView class, and inside of it ther is a member of mymodel. i think the error is this, the type of datacontext it's different.

Comment: The `DataContext = ...` I've set was just an example, you should populate it by other means, e.g. an open file button or whatever. Now take a look at the docs of `DataContext` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx), this is inherited in the hierarchy, the `ListBox` in the window inherits it, i.e. there is no need to directly work with the ListBox, ever. Hope that makes sense to you :D

Comment: i tried to change like this d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyModel}", using directly the model class(
like you 've written), but it's the same, the Datacontext in the user control it's always null...

Comment: Thank you @Aybe, i added in Mymodel Class an empty constructur and i was abilitate to use in the DataContext of view, and now it's ok.